# Assign a JavaScript variable to dropdown text field

Tags: javascript

I want to assign a JavaScript variable to a dropdown text field but the result is the dropdown's value, not its text.

```js
var state = document.getElementById("categoryselect_level_0").value;
document.getElementById("fad").value = state;
```

```html
<select class="categoryselect_cascade" id="categoryselect_level_0">
  <option value="9" class="0">- a1</option>
  <option value="13" class="0">- a2</option>
  <option value="30" class="0">- a3</option>
  <option value="51" class="0">- a4</option>
  <option value="69" class="0">- a5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="fad" value="" />
```

With ***(state=9)***, I expect ***state= - a1***, not 9.

And is there a way to strip "-" character from the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```html
<select class="categoryselect_cascade" id="categoryselect_level_0">
                            
<option value="9" class="0">- a1</option>
<option value="13" class="0">- a2</option>
<option value="30" class="0">- a3</option>
<option value="51" class="0">- a4</option>
<option value="69" class="0">- a5</option>
</select>


<input type="text" id="fad" value="" />

<script>
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("categoryselect_level_0");
    var selectedIndex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
    var state = selectedIndex !== -1 ? dropdown.options[selectedIndex].text : "";
    
    // Strip "-" character from the text
    state = state.replace(/^- /, "");

    document.getElementById("fad").value = state;
</script>
```

Here is the alternate approach that if you want to update the input field based on the selected option

```js
function updateInput() {
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("categoryselect_level_0");
        var selectedIndex = dropdown.selectedIndex;
        var state = selectedIndex !== -1 ? dropdown.options[selectedIndex].text : "";

        // Strip "-" character from the text
        state = state.replace(/^- /, "");

        document.getElementById("fad").value = state;
    }

    // Add an event listener to the dropdown for the "change" event
    document.getElementById("categoryselect_level_0").addEventListener("change", updateInput);

    // Initial call to set the initial value
    updateInput();
```

```html
<select class="categoryselect_cascade" id="categoryselect_level_0">
    <option value="9" class="0">- a1</option>
    <option value="13" class="0">- a2</option>
    <option value="30" class="0">- a3</option>
    <option value="51" class="0">- a4</option>
    <option value="69" class="0">- a5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="fad" value="" />
```